# Conditions on polynomials with common roots.

Tags: quadratics

If one root of the equation $x^2 + ax + b = 0$ and $x^2 + bx + a = 0$ is common and $a \ne b$ then:

The options are as follows:
$$\begin{array}{ll}
(A)\quad& a + b = 0\\
(B)& a + b = -1\\
(C)& a - b = 1\\
(D)& a + b = 1
\end{array}$$

Idk how to solve this, please help me.

Comment: You should show what you've tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $c$ be the common root. Then
$$c^2+ac+b=0$$
$$c^2+bc+a=0$$
so $ac+b=bc+a$ or $(a-b)c=a-b$. Since $a\neq b$, $c$ must be $1$.

Now we have $a+b=-1$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Substitute the common root and subtract.

Answer (score 0):

$x^2+ax+b=x^2+bx+a$ => $(a-b)(x-1)=0$.  Since $a \neq b$, $x=1$. Thus $1^2+a+b=0$. Hence, $a+b=-1$.

Thus, C is the answer.